# My NextJS component cannot get data from my Flask server

Tags: flask, next.js, fetch-api

The issue is that my Fetch request inside my NextJS component can fetch data from dummy api's correctly(ex. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) but does not fetch data from my Flask API. Nothing is displayed when I refresh the page.

There is this error message in console but I don't know what it means:

```
Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted
    at useRouter (navigation.js:126:15)
    at HotReload (hot-reloader-client.js:367:46)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:9745:28)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:14632:25)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:15936:32)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22789:28)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:21852:24)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:21617:17)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:21584:21)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:20917:30)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20871:46)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:200:48)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:178:28)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:416:35)
```

`

Here are my NextJS components:

```
import CatalogList from "./CatalogList";

export default function Catalog(){
    return(
        <main>
            <h2>Catalog</h2>
            <CatalogList/>
        </main>
    )
}
```

```
async function getItems(){
    const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/catalog')
    return res.json()
}



export default async function CatalogList(){
    const data = await getItems()
    const items = data.items
    return(
       <>
        <h3>should work</h3>
        {items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
                <h3>{item.id}</h3>
            </div>
        ))}
       </>
    )
}
```

Here is my Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.secret_key = "SSMIF"
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=10)


@app.route("/heartbeat")
def heartbeat():
    return jsonify({"status": "healthy"})


# A request to add items to the catalog (use the request body to store data)
@app.route("/catalog/item", methods=["POST"])
def add_item():
    # takes incoming json, converts to python, converts objects to dictionaries and arrays to lists
    session.permanent=True
    data = request.get_json()
    id = data["id"]
    name = data['name']
    price = data['price']
    quantity = data['quantity']
    link = data['link']
    session[id] = {"id": id,"name": name, "price": price, "quantity": quantity, "link": link}
    return jsonify({'result': 'success!','id': id ,'name': name, 'price': price, 'quantity': quantity, "link": link})

@app.route("/catalog/item", methods=["PUT"])
def update_item():
    data = request.get_json()
    id = data["id"]
    if id == None:
        return jsonify({'result': 'Item does not exist. Send a POST request instead.'})
    if id in session:
        item = session[id]
        name = item.get("name","")
        price = item.get("price", "")
        quantity = item.get("quantity","")
        link = item.get("link","")
        if 'name' in data:
            name = data["name"]
        if 'price' in data:
            price = data["price"]
        if 'quantity' in data:
            quantity = data["quantity"]
        if 'link' in data:
            link = data["link"]
        session[id] = {"id": id,"name": name, "price": price, "quantity": quantity, "link": link}
        return jsonify({'result': 'success!','id': id ,'name': name, 'price': price, 'quantity': quantity, "link": link})
    else:
        return jsonify({'result': 'Item does not exist. Send a POST request instead.'})



# A request to remove items from the catalog using an item id
@app.route("/catalog/item/<item_id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def remove_item(item_id):
    session.pop(item_id, None)
    return jsonify({"result":'success!'})


# A request to get all items in the catalog
@app.route("/catalog", methods=["GET"])
def get_items():
    return_items = []
    for key, items in session.items():
        if is_string(key) and isinstance(item, dict): 
            return_items.append(items)
    return jsonify({"items": return_items})


# ... implement any other routes you need or want to use below ... #


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm not sure how to solve this. I am a beginner.